# How do I disable TextBox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

earlier I asked for help disabling a Button when a drop down menu item was selected. I was given some code that did the trick but now I need the same with a Textbox and for some odd reason its not working can you have a look for me...

HTML:

```
<form id="frmColor">
    <input type='TextBox' id='color' />
    <input type='submit' value='Change Color' id="colorSubmit"/>
 </form>
```

Javascript:

```
  tools.eraser = function () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;
    var varPenColor = "White";
    context.strokeStyle = varPenColor;
    document.getElementById('frmColor').colorSubmit.disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('frmColor').color.disabled=true;
```

Any ideas why it wont disable the text box?

Thanks

Comment: type TextBox don't exists ... use instead `<input type="text" id="color" />`
[link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Form elements can be accessed via the form's DOM element by *name*, not by "id" value.  Give your form elements names if you want to access them like that, or else access them directly by "id" value:

```
document.getElementById("color").disabled = true;
```

*edit* — oh also, as pointed out by others, it's just "text", not "TextBox", for the "type" attribute.

You might want to invest a little time in reading some front-end development tutorials.

Answer (score 5):

With the help of jquery it can be done as follows.

```
$("#color").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: jQuery is not JavaScript. please do not answer JavaScript questions with jQuery responses.

Comment: actually it is.  It's written entirely in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Here was my solution:

Markup:

```
<div id="name" disabled="disabled">
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("name").disabled = true;
```

This the best solution for my applications - hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use disabled attribute to disable the textbox.

```
document.getElementById('color').disabled = true;
```

Comment: The accepted answer has already provided the solution you recommend 5+ years ago!