# Restrict keyboard Input to Textbox JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do i restrict user to enter any data from Keyboard to Text-box. Actually my requirement is that, this particular textbox is being used for only scanning purpose. Hence, only scanned data will be entered to this textbox and want to restrict any manually entered data from keyboard.

Comment: Can we see some code of what you are doing?

Answer (score 2):

Just disable the textbox and get the value from the backend will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ujsEG/112/)

I dont think there is any need of javascript here.

Just use **readonly** in you html.

```
 <input value="somevalue" name="meow" readonly>
```

Thats it.No fancy javascript needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
   $('input[type=text]').bind('keyup keydown keypress', function (evt) {
       return false;
   });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gDE27/)

Comment: This is an overkill.. Just setting a readonly attribute should do

Comment: @Sushanth-- Yes you are right but he don't want disable in question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill data from backend then you can permanently disable 
for that you just need to add in textbox html readonly and then fill value by

```
document.getElementById("yourtextbox_id").value="your_scanned_value";
```

Comment: for reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624988/javascript-disable-textbox

Comment: you post your question in javascript that's why i post answer with javascript solution otherwise @VAGABOND has a right solution

Comment: Unfortunately its not working. I want to allow only input from barcode scanner. And restrict to any field from keyboard.

Comment: So please mention it in your question, you wrote half of the things you need.............. i am updating my answer one minute

Comment: and my previous answer and this is working well dear just check your code. May be you wrote something wrong there